# SQL Join For Nonexistant Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have the following query but it only pulls records that exist in both tables.  How can I modify it so that it still pulls if a record does not exist in Table_Sold?

```
 SELECT  Col_1 ,
        Col_2 - Sold AS Remaining_Stock
FROM    Table_1
        JOIN ( SELECT   Col_3 ,
                        SUM(Col_2) AS Sold
               FROM     Table_2
               GROUP BY Col_3
             ) AS Table_Sold ON Table_1.Col_1 = Table_Sold.Col_3
                                AND Col_2 > Sold
```

Comment: which rdbms is this for? you tagged three different ones.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a regular `JOIN`.

```
SELECT Col_1, Col_2 - coalesce(Sold, 0) AS Remaining_Stock
FROM Table_1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT Col_3, SUM(Col_2) AS Sold
  FROM Table_2
  GROUP BY Col_3) AS Table_Sold 
ON Table_1.Col_1 = Table_Sold.Col_3
   AND Col_2 > Sold; -- This last condition is probably ambiguous
```

Comment: I have tried this.  This pulls all records that have null values from the Table_Sold.  I only want the records that have remaining stock.

Comment: That is not what you asked for. But if I understand your comment correctly then the updated answer should solve it. Using a `LEFT JOIN` you get all rows from the first table and corresponding rows from the joined table. Missing rows for the joined table get the `NULL` value and that messes up your select list so you should substitute `0` for `NULL` on the `sold` field.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a `LEFT JOIN` situation

```
SELECT Col_1, Col_2 - Sold as Remaining_Stock 
FROM Table_1 
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT Col_3, SUM(Col_2) as Sold 
FROM Table_2 GROUP BY Col_3) as Table_Sold
ON Table_1.Col_1 = Table_Sold.Col_3 AND Col_2 > Sold
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id, a.qty - ifnull(o.qty,0) remaining_stock
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT product_id, sum(qty) qty
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY 1
) o ON p.id = o.product_id
WHERE a.qty > o.qty
```